# xkill keyboard shortcut does not work on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: keyboard

I am at the end of my tether with Ubuntu at this stage.

I create a simple shortcut under keyboard 'Ctrl + K' for xkill.

I hit Ctrl + K ..... nothing happens.

I open a terminal, type in xkill and it works fine.

Running Ubuntu 13.10 saucy and fglrx beta drivers.

Other keyboard shortcuts like logout work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You probably moved on by now. For other people to reference...

I had the same issue in version 12.04. Heres how to do it:

1. System Settings->Keyboard->Shortcuts
2. click the '+' button
3. type 'xkill' for name
4. type 'xkill' for command

I assume you were typing 'Ctrl+Alt+X' for the command (thats what i was doing). However, 'command' does not refer to the shortcut keys, but to the actual command used to run the program. I know, im a newb.

Then press apply and click where it says 'disabled' next to the new xkill command and press the keys you want to use for your shortcut. Now you should be able to use that shortcut to execute the 'xkill' command.

From reading other forums, it appears as though logging out and then logging back in becomes necessary in version 13.10 in order for shortcuts to take effect.